# Python: convert datetime format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've a string in the following date/time format:

> 2018-05-20T07:06:23.226

I need to convert it to the following format:

> 2018-05-20 06:23 AM

I tried the following code, but I'm surely making some mistake here:

```
date = "2018-05-20T07:06:23.226"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('date', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
new_date = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
```

I always get the following error:

> ValueError: time data 'date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

Comment: This is a typo and should be closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

replace:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('date', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

with

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Also

```
new_date = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
```

with

```
new_date = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: I can't believe I wasted 15 minutes for a typo. I need to get some sleep.

Comment: What's the difference in the last 2 pieces of code?

Comment: the year format `%y` is two digit (like 99) `%Y` is four digit (like 1999)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use variable inside string, you can do it since Python 3.6:

```
date = "2018-05-20T07:06:23.226"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{date}', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
new_date = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M %p')
```