# How to convert following date time format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have to convert `1/1/2016 0:00` into  `2016-01-01 00:00:00`

Current method used:

```
datetime.strptime((1/1/2016 0:00, "%m %d %Y %I:%M")
```

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '1/1/2016 0:00' does not match format '%m %d %Y %I:%M'
```

Comment: `datetime.strptime("1/1/2016 0:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: convert datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445544/python-convert-datetime-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3.6 you can do it with this:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime('1/1/2016 0:00', "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```